Can for results of suggested actions
Do we use the modal "can" to suggest that someone should do something to achieve a favorable result?
For example,
A: I don't know what he wants to say.
B: Well, he's obviously deaf. If you give him a pen, he can write down what he wants to say.
Does A mean the part in bold is a preferable result if B does what he suggests?

"preferable" is just a contextual association (without the pen, he can't). can has its normal meaning of be able to (do something; in this case, achieve the desired act of communicating).

@FumbleFingers What I want to ask is whether A is suggesting B should do something to achieve the result that he desires, which, in this case, is communication.

B tells A that if he does something, this will enable somebody else to do something that A wants. Which may be the best thing to do, but not necessarily. Maybe B will go on to say that giving the other person a pen is a bad option. Perhaps B thinks A should give the guy a smartphone running an app that just reads out whatever he types.

Yeah you are right. I misplace A and B. B is the one suggesting A should do something to achieve something he desires.

You can always edit your question!

Here "can" strongly implies that he will be able to do it. "Could" would be less forceful, suggesting that he might be able to do it but for whatever reason he may not. "He should be able to" has more of a sense of a preferable outcome but it's still context dependent.

Yes, it's fine in this case.

Does this answer your question? Use of "Can" x "Could"

I'm not sure this example does the best job of illustrating the idea you're asking about. Consider this one instead: A Mr. Smith is in his boss's office, and the boss wants him to leave:

"Thank you Smith, I think we're done here. You can leave the door open."

Here "can" is a bit of a euphemism. It's a request—an order, since it comes from the boss—but it's softened using the language of a suggestion.
Or this example:

"Welcome to the inn, weary traveler! You can leave your bags with Stephan here. I'm sure you're hungry; you can get a bowl of stew in the dining room over here."

There's no coercion here; it's not an order; but the context is such that the traveler's needs are understood and assumed, and the innkeeper is simply directing them about how to do it.
So here are two examples in which "can" "suggests that someone should do something." But as usual, the distinction is created by context.
